# Is it possible to configure a Sata RAID Controller without RAID

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata

I have a 6 port SATA RAID card (taken out of an HP ML150 G2 server). What i want to do is connect the Sata Hard Drives that i have to this card without formatting or loosing any data on the hard drive.

Can this be done. And also i do not want to create a RAID Array, I just want to install the hard drives without RAID.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why all dislikes? This seems like a proper question to me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question may depend quite a bit on the software embedded/provided with that card (even changing from one revision/update to the next).

I'd make sure to have a relevant number of SCRATCH DRIVES to play with, then try it out with them: build knowledge suitable for the situation at hand.